# HTML5 native Drag and Drop : Is it possible to change the preview while dragging an element?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, html5-draggable

I would like to change the preview while dragging an element. (see [setDragImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setDragImage))

Like using another element if the user hit ctrl or shift for instance while dragging ?

This is an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/js-drag-drop-example-with-preview-n9gpc). This example display an image when you start the drag action. However if you want to change it on the fly it's quite chanllenging !

Is it even possible ?